# Stacking divs with fixed placeholder (and maintaining during animation)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz4uegxv/31/). Thank you in advance!

I'm trying to run an animation where one word slides in to replace an existing word.

**Stacking** - I can stack the divs using *absolute* but I cannot seem to wrap the div so it retains it's desired place. (i.e. I want the Incoming/Outgoing text in the red box)

**Animation** - The divs want to stack when both animations are running (after the delay is over for animation number 2). Am I unable to run both "inline/absolute"?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Action').click(function(e) {
    //start incoming
    Enter('#Incoming', 'fadeInRight');
    //add minor delay and then start outgoing
    setTimeout(function() {
      ExitAndHide('#Outgoing', 'fadeOutLeft');
    }, 2000);

  });
});

//outgoing function
function ExitAndHide(item, action) {
  $(item).removeClass().addClass(action + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
    $(item).hide();
  });
};

//incoming function
function Enter(item, action) {
  $(item).css("display", "inline-block");
  $(item).removeClass().addClass(action + ' animated');
};
```

```css
.stackable {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

.fadeOutLeft {
  animation-name: fadeOutLeft
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0)
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none
  }
}

.fadeInRight {
  animation-name: fadeInRight
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}

@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container2">
      Content Should be here
    </div>
    <div id=Outgoing class="stackable">
      <strong>Outgoing</strong>
    </div>
    <div id=Incoming class="stackable">
      <strong>Incoming</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id=Action>Action</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the content in the `<div class="container2">` element, then that is where you should place it in your HTML.

```
<div class=" text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container2">

      <div id="Outgoing" class="stackable">
        <strong>Outgoing</strong>
      </div>
      <div id="Incoming" class="stackable">
        <strong>Incoming</strong>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>      
  <button id=Action>Action</button>
</div>
```

I would also add `overflow: hidden` to `.container2` in CSS.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cLwhfbj9/8/) ---- [DCML] updated to version with answer

Unfortunately the code snippets only support up to version 2.1.1 of jQuery.

**[ EDIT ]**

Notably, you're missing the quotes around `id=Outgoing` and `id=Incoming`. You must also actually apply `position: absolute` to these elements, in which case you're also going to need to apply a `height` value to `.container`, since `.container` will not respect the "inherent height" of elements with `position: absolute`.

JSFIDDLE and the code snippet have been updated accordingly.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#Action').click(function(e) {
    //start incoming
    Enter('#Incoming', 'fadeInRight');
    //add minor delay and then start outgoing
    setTimeout(function() {
      ExitAndHide('#Outgoing', 'fadeOutLeft');
    }, 2000);

  });
});

//outgoing function
function ExitAndHide(item, action) {
  $(item).removeClass().addClass(action + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
    $(item).hide();
  });
};

//incoming function
function Enter(item, action) {
  $(item).css("display", "inline-block");
  $(item).removeClass().addClass(action + ' animated');
};
```

```css
#Incoming, #Outgoing {
  position: absolute;
}

.stackable {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fadeOutLeft {
  animation-name: fadeOutLeft
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0)
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none
  }
}

.fadeInRight {
  animation-name: fadeInRight
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}

@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container2">

      <div id="Outgoing" class="stackable">
        <strong>Outgoing</strong>
      </div>
      <div id="Incoming" class="stackable">
        <strong>Incoming</strong>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>      
  <button id=Action>Action</button>
</div>
```

Comment: **"overflow: hidden;"** answers the first part, thank you. However there is still a line break when the two animations "connect". I believe this is due to the animation framework not respecting absolute positioning and I'm wondering if there is a way around that.

Comment: @DontCallMeLarry i figured it out and updated my answer!